# Как считывать данные с веб-камеры компьютера

Tags: c#, web-camera

Веб-камера является одним из подключаемых (иногда - встроенных) устройств компьютера.

Каким образом можно считать данные, которые она передаёт, а также преобразовать их в «читаемый» вид?

Как вообще проходит работа с подобными устройствами на уровне системы?

Comment: Посмотрите исходники этих самых библиотек и узнаете)

Comment: Вы чисто из спортивного интереса хотите узнать, как это работает? Или же у Вас проект с указанным требованием?

Comment: Из споритивного

Comment: ну, в плане для себя, для общего развития, чтобы понимать в принципе, как это работает (а, это не вопрос, Вы сначала просто "?" поставили)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Извините, я уже исправил прошлый коммент, да из спортивного

Comment: Тогда похвально) Я попробую расписать это дело на выходных, там будет много текста хД

Comment: понимаете, у Вас подача в вопросе была: «Возьмите и сделайте за меня». Там не было видно, что Вы хотите просто разобраться в проблеме. Нулевое у нас очень не любят и часто минусуют. Первое же наоборот похвально. Все зависит от того, как Вы подали свой вопрос ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: От меня - плюс, считаю вопрос достойным внимания

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Прежде чем писать вопрос на этот сайт, я ищу ответ в интернете, я читал исходники разных бибилиотек, но почти ничего не понял, так что задал вопрос сюда т.к. здесь находятся эксперты, я сам не люблю задавать вопросы по типу "сделайте за меня"

Comment: чуток поработайте над оформлением своих вопросов, не стесняйтесь добавлять, что информацию Вы искали, видели то-то и то-то, пытались сделать так-то, да и вообще просто хотите **понять**) Я всегда стараюсь находить посты новичков и немного править их, чтобы хорошие по сути своей вопросы не минусовали и они не уходили в небытие)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Мне казалось, что вопрос должен быть компактным. В общем жду ответ на выходных, спасибо!

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Ах да, если не трудно, не могли бы вы написать, как можно сделать на основе полученных данных, детектор движения(Если знаете конечно)

Comment: да, в вопросе не стоит указывать, например, что Вы размышляли над проблемой, пока гуляли с собакой, к примеру, так как это не совсем относится ко всему происходящему. А вот любые Ваши действия в сторону решения/поиска такового указанной задачи, любые Ваши мысли на этот счёт - это важная информация, которую указать стоит)

Comment: будем объективны, «детектор движения» - это уже другой вопрос. Подобного не делал, но, как мне кажется, нужно смотреть на % различия изображений за разные временной период. Можно кэшировать картинку при точно статичных обстоятельствах, а потом сравнивать ее с текущими данными через какой-то интервал

Comment: Если вы планируете использовать в замкнутых пространствах, то проще использовать более примитивные способы для определения движения. Например, датчики движения на Arduino.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov А как можно получать "процент" различия изображения?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Там тоже используется библиотека

Comment: И? Написать программу для захвата видео с камеры "без библиотек" невозможно, так как системные Avicap32.dll, quartz.dll  и т.п., содержащие компоненты для работы с видео, тоже, внезапно, являются библиотеками.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Я надеюсь вы не забыли про этот вопрос?

Comment: @Log1c0 не забыл. У меня тут был пожар, который немного уничтожил мой дом, так что было немного не до ответов/вопросов на ruSO

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Соболезную, надеюсь никто не пострадал.

Comment: @Log1c0 спасибо... Кроме дома, обратившегося в пепел, никто

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Извините, я все понимаю, но все же, не могли бы ответить, просто не терпится(еще раз извините)